# Mongo - equivalence between distinct and aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, distinct

Hi: I'm facing some issues whe replacing the distinct 'native' function of mongo with an aggregate query.

In my case my query is like:

```js
db.collection.distinct('stuff.shape')
```

mongo then returns an array with distinct values of object.field like

```
['square','triangle','circle']
```

but douing with aggregate

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
{   $match:{ 'stuff.shape':{$exists: true} }  },
{   $group:{ '_id': '$stuff.shape'}   }
])
```

returns many elements like

```
{'_id':['triangle']}
{'_id':['square']}
{'_id':['circle']}
```

my goal is getting the same list as native aggregate.

This is because the expression I want to "distinct" has some calculated data I can't put in the distinct directly

sample data:

```
[
  {
    "type": "obligation",
    "stuff": {
      "name": "must-turn-right",
      "shape": "circle"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "information",
    "stuff": {
      "name": "town_name",
      "shape": "square"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "obligation",
    "stuff": {
      "name": "yeld",
      "shape": "triangle"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "danger",
    "stuff": {
      "name": "beware_of_cattle",
      "shape": "triangle"
    }
  }
]
```

[link to mongoplaygroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fpLg1pTw24d)

Comment: `Aggregate` returns an array of objects, so you can't get an array of strings like `['square','triangle','circle']`. However the closest you can get is an array of an object with a field containing the expected array like this `[{ _id: ['square','triangle','circle'] }]`. You can achieve this by using another `$group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @thammada.ts already said, it's not possible to get an array of strings from the `aggregate` function that is equivalent to the output of the `distinct` function.

It is possible to create an aggregate query that returns one document with the distinct values as an array in the document by adding an extra `$group` stage in the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{   $match:{ 'stuff.shape':{$exists: true} }  },
{   $group:{ '_id': '$stuff.shape'}   },
{   $group:{ '_id': null, 'shape': {$push: '$_id'}}}
])
```

gives output

```
[{
  "_id": null,
  "shape": [
    "square",
    "circle",
    "triangle"
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation pipeline returns documents. If you want an array of field values, you need to perform that transformation in your application.